# Save value from visualforce page to controller

Tags: visualforce

I want to show a visual force page with a text field when the stage of an opportunity is changed to closed won. On clicking save I want to:

1. save the value in Opportunity record
2. can i somehow open the vf page as a pop up?

Comment: can someone help me with an example. this will be my first vf code

Comment: I believe you will need to override the save button and make the logic.